# compare_numbers.h:83: warning: passing 'double' for argument 2 to 'int mongo::compareLongs(long long int, long long int)'

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I want compile mongo c++ driver in  RHEL 5, but when use `scons`, Error is :

```
compare_numbers.h:83: warning: passing 'double' for argument 2 to 'int mongo::compareLongs(long long int, long long int)'
scons: *** [build/linux2/normal/mongo/bson/bsonelement.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

What is this ?

Comment: You're passing a `double`. The function expects a `long long int`, and apparently the compile flags are such warnings are treated as errors?

Comment: You have an error on line 83 of `compare_numbers.h`. Apparently, you're passing a `double` where you should be passing a `long long int`. That's what the error says.

Comment: i just use `scons` in mongo-cxx-driver-legacy directory, without extra code

Comment: If the code is not yours, then you're probably using a compiler which is more strict than the one the developers use. Check that you use the last version of the code and if so, report the issue upstream.

Comment: Someone's been abusing the fact that `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long long)` on most sane architectures. Remove the -Werror and pray.

Comment: my gcc version is 4.1.2